# 4x4 Matrix (3D) animation

Tags: animation, matrix, 3d

I'm currently trying to animate a 3D object from one transform matrix to another. I know the "origin" and "target" transform matrix (4x4), and would like to get the "intermediate" matrices between to do an animation with a "progress" variable [0, 1].

For example, I could go from:

```
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1
```

To:

```
0.70711  -0.70711  0  0
0.70711   0.70711  0  0
      0         0  1  0
      0         0  0  1
```

It's a simple 45deg rotation, and I would like to be able to find intermediate matrix for a **0.5** progression for example. Of course, here it's simple, and I perfectly know how to animate it, but I which for an algorithm able to work for more complex transform matrices (one which contains translations, rotations on multiple axis and scaling).

I found some articles:

- https://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/838-s2002/Papers/polar-decomp.pdf
- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-016-0098-7

And even search on the chrome and firefox source code which use this kind of algorithm to animate css transform property: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/2ca8c5037021c9d2ecc00b787d58a31ed8fc8bcb/cc/animation/transform_operation.cc

Sadly, I was not able to find a clear solution. No authors provide a proper algorithm (the ones provided are extremely abstract and doesn't specify their "sub-functions/algorithm"). Only a very few papers are available. And finally they don't provide any example (from one matrix to another) so it's almost impossible to verify their method.

Has any of you already faced this problem and implemented a solution ? Clear example, or pseudo code would be perfect, if someone knows the answer.

In any case, thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

So, I finally found a solution: the w3c provides an algorithm to interpolate the transform matrices: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-2/#matrix-interpolation

It works in 3 steps:

- [decomposition](https://github.com/lifaon74/alter/blob/develop/src/tests/experimental/animations/transitions/mat4/decompose.ts): splits the matrix in translation, scaling, skewing, perspective and rotation (quaternion) vectors
- [interpolation](https://github.com/lifaon74/alter/blob/develop/src/tests/experimental/animations/transitions/mat4/interpolate.ts): creates interpolated new vectors from the previous ones
- [recomposition](https://github.com/lifaon74/alter/blob/develop/src/tests/experimental/animations/transitions/mat4/recompose.ts): compose a transform matrix from these vectors

It may not be the faster but it does the job.